# Floated divs rendered differently to absolutely positioned divs at different zoom levels

Tags: html, css, zooming

I'm building a page like a calendar, which has grid cells representing time periods, and then appointment blocks overlaying that grid that can be created by the user.  Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qe8kZ/), and here's the code from the fiddle

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    ...
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="block" style="width:48px;left:-1px"></div>
    <div class="block" style="width:48px;left:149px"></div>
    <div class="block" style="width: 198px; left: 249px;"></div>
    <div class="block" style="width: 48px; left: 549px;"></div>
    <div class="block" style="width:48px;left:1099px"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  min-height:100px;
  overflow:auto;
  border:1px solid #000000;
  -ms-overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  position:relative;
}

.row {
  position:relative;
  height:20px;
  width: 1200px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom:2px;
}

.cell {
  height:18px;
  float:left;
  border:1px dotted #DDDDDD;
  text-align:center;
  width: 48px;
}

.block {
  position:absolute;
  height:16px;
  border:2px solid #236B8E;
  background-color: #A7C4D2;  
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

My problem is that in some browsers (and at non-X00% zoom levels in all browsers I've tested) the absolutely positioned appointment blocks don't render the same distance from the left of their container compared to the equivalent number of grid cells.

Eg one of the blocks has `left: 549px;` (not 550px because of the 2px border). So it SHOULD be positioned exactly over the 12th grid cell div.  That is the case when zoom is set at 100% (Chrome 30 on XP SP3), but set it to 150% and it doesn't overlap the grid cell anymore.  Set it to 200% and it's fine again. And so on...

Worse still is that on some browser/OS combinations it doesn't render nicely even at 100% zoom - Firefox 25 on Win 7 64 bit SP1 is one such combination (where as FF22 & 25 are both fine on XP SP3).

Note that pinch zooming on my Xoom Android tablet had no such problems (I tried the standard Android browser and Chrome).

I'm guessing that this is caused by something like [this](http://robertnyman.com/2008/01/24/how-web-browsers-handle-rounding-when-it-comes-to-values-set-in-percentage/) - ie the left/width values of absolutely positioned items (blocks: 48px + 2px border = 52px positioned with -1px offset) vs floated items (grid cells: the 48px + 1px border = 50px each) producing different rounding errors when multiplied by 150% etc.

Or maybe it's BECAUSE of the floating vs absolute positioning?  I'm less convinced of that.

Any ideas how I can get a proper cross-browser/OS solution that also works with non-X00% zoom levels?

EDIT: My hunch was wrong. Absolute positioning the grid cells worked, at least on Chrome on XP.  [Fiddle to prove it.](http://jsfiddle.net/zrer8/1/)

Comment: Yes, rounding errors. Solution: either position the cells absolutely as well, or, put each of the absolute blocks inside the cell that they belong in.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks! I didn't think absolute positioning everything would work, but it did. Didn't try your second suggestion. It's probably good too, but more complex to work into my code.